# How do I use CLLocationManager in an OS X Today Extension?

Tags: swift, macos, core-location, today-extension

I'm trying to get the user's location in a Today Extension and I'm hitting a dead end.

On an OS X app, when you call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`, a dialog pops up asking if you want to let the app use your location. In the Today view, though, nothing comes up at all after calling this method, and my delegate doesn't get called for `didUpdateLocations` or for `didFailWithError`. `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` returns `NotDetermined`. I have been looking at Apple's docs on Today Extensions and am not seeing much about permissions or about getting the user's location.

How are we intended to get the user's location in an OS X Today Extension?

Edit: One thing to note is that `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` returns `true` on my OS X app and `false` on my Today Extension. What does this mean, and how can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X Today Extensions use an App Sandbox by default and you need to check the right boxes to allow the Today Extension to do things like get the user's location and make network calls.

Go to your **project settings** in Xcode, select your OS X Today Extension target, click the **Capabilities** tab, expand the **App Sandbox** section, and check the boxes for the capabilities you want (in my case, Location and Outgoing Network Connections).